# Mule 4 : how to generate a Text file from an Array

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I have to generate a text file from an Array. To do this, I am taking the following approach :

1. Creating a Java Array from the json payload using Dataweave map method
2. Using a For each component to iterate over the Array
3. Using a File:Write Component inside the foreach and writing the element by converting them to String as follows : `write(payload,"application/java")` and setting the File Write Mode to Append

Is there any better way to achieve this?

Example of Array :

```
[["Amam","ssss","Bibek","Raghu","Rajeev"],["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pineapple","Pears"]]
```

And in text file I want the output to be as :

```
Amam ssss Bibek Raghu Rajeev 
Apple Banana Orange Pineapple Pears
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
var inputText = [
  ["Amam","ssss","Bibek","Raghu","Rajeev"], 
  ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pineapple","Pears"]
] 
---
(inputText map ($ joinBy " ")) joinBy "\n"
```

This is with the input formatted as Olivier was using in the previous answer.

As mentioned the input format:

```
[{"Amam","ssss","Bibek","Raghu","Rajeev"},{"Apple","Banana","Orange","Pineapple","Pears"}]
```

as originally given is not valid JSON or Java and DW will throw errors when attempting to parse it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate over the array using a foreach. You can use directly the File:Write component, with the following dataweave expression in the its "content" property:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv header=false
---
payload map (item, index) -> val: item joinBy " "
```

This dataweave expression with the following input:

```
[
  ["Amam","ssss","Bibek","Raghu","Rajeev"], 
  ["Apple","Banana","Orange","Pineapple","Pears"]
]
```

Results in:

```
Amam ssss Bibek Raghu Rajeev
Apple Banana Orange Pineapple Pears
```

Although the output format in the Dataweave expression is CSV, the resulting file will be a text file containing the resulting output (the file name is determined by the "path" property of the File:Write component, and can be something like "my-text-file.txt", for example).

Supported output formats and their properties are described here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats

Comment: @Oliver Hey Thanks for our answer, but my objective is to write a TEXT file and not a CSV file.

Comment: Could you please provide the text file layout or an example of the output you are expecting? Thank you.

Comment: Attached an example of my input and expected output. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, @Bibek. I could not parse the example array you provided. Maybe you java array is an array of array of strings? Something like: `[["val1.1", "val1.2"],["val2.1", "val2.2"]]`. If you have your flow implemented, you can debug it in Studio and evaluate the payload message part and see how it looks when the output is application/json.

Comment: @BibekKr.Bazaz it doesn't matter if it is a CSV. That's just a format for text files. If the final text file is exactly what you want, then it is OK.

Comment: @Oliver Sorry for the typo.. instead of [] , i used {}

Comment: Thank you all for the amazing lead to joinBy method. It helped me in a lot of scenarios